# Why Recyclerview doesn't scroll inside AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a layout with `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and `RecyclerView`. I am facing scroll issue when add `RecyclerView` inside `AppBarLayout`, `RecyclerView` never scroll while `AppBarLayout` is expanded or collapsed

Here is my whole project, Where is the issue?

MainActivity

```
package com.example.coordinatorlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView rvItems;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
private ItemModel itemModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rvItems = findViewById(R.id.rv_products);

    invalidateView(  setListItems());
}

private List<ItemModel> setListItems() {
    List<ItemModel> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemModel = new ItemModel();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        itemModel = new ItemModel();
        itemModel.setName("Name_" + i);
        itemModel.setPrice("10");
        itemModel.setStock(i + 2);

        itemsList.add(i, itemModel);
    }

    return itemsList;
}


private void invalidateView(List<ItemModel> items) {
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    rvItems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    rvItems.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(items);
    rvItems.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
  }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_top_corners_rectangle_gray"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_view" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ItemModel

```
package com.example.coordinatorlayout;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ItemModel implements Parcelable {

private String name;
private String price;
private int stock;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String iName) {
    this.name = iName;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String iPrice) {
    this.price = iPrice;
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(int iStock) {
    this.stock = iStock;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.price);
    dest.writeInt(this.stock);
}

public ItemModel() {
}

protected ItemModel(Parcel in) {
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.price = in.readString();
    this.stock = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<ItemModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ItemModel>() {
    @Override
    public ItemModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ItemModel(source);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ItemModel[size];
    }
  };
}
```

ItemAdapter

```
package com.example.coordinatorlayout;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<ItemModel> itemsList;

public ItemAdapter(List<ItemModel> list) {
    this.itemsList = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemModel product = itemsList.get(position);
    holder.bindData(product);
}

public void setData(List<ItemModel> list) {
    this.itemsList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvQuantity;
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvPrice;

    MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tvQuantity = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity);
        tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
    }

    void bindData(ItemModel item) {
        tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(item.getStock()));
        tvName.setText(item.getName());
        tvPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
    }
  }
 }
```

item_view.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_main_item_container_product"
android:layout_width="140dp"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_quantity_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_quantity_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_quantity_title"
    tools:text="5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_quantity_title"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:text="Product" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tv_price_currency"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_price_currency"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    tools:text="$" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_price_currency"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_price_currency"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    tools:text="5" />
```

round_top_corners_rectangle_gray.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#F9F9F9" />
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="33dp"
    android:topRightRadius="33dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** You need to use the `RecyclerView` inside the `Coordinatorlayout` and outside of the `AppBarLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/prof_item" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The first layout you've added to the question has many issues. **First**, `CoordintorLayout` should be the root of the layout.

**Second**, if you're trying to add some content at the top of the layout, you'll need to use the `RelativeLayout` inside the `AppBarLayout` or using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside the `AppBarLayout`.

Another problem is that you've added:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

To the `RecyclerView` which is only used outside of `AppBarLayout` to notify the `AppBarLayout` when scroll events occur on this particular view. So remove this attribute.

Comment: I updated the question with the new layout as suggested but now the view doesn't expand or collapse, the whole screen is static.

Comment: You're still using `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` &  `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` in the `RelativeLayout`. You should consider using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in the `AppBarLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` or in above of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I removed `RelativeLayout` and added `CollapsingToolbarLayout` I am still facing the same issue, `RecyclerView` doesn't scroll( Code updated)

Comment: Just one question, are you trying to use `RecyclerView` inside `AppBarLayout` or, you want to have the `RecyclerView` scroll while  `AppBarLayout` expends/collapses? Because the way I see, you're trying to have  `RecyclerView` and  `AppBarLayout a part from the each other.

Comment: I want to have the `RecyclerView` scroll while `AppBarLayout` expends

Comment: Please check my updated answer. `RecyclerView` should be inside of the `CoordinatorLayout`. You can also use the custom logo inside the `Toolbar` (if you're trying to add a custom logo. That's related to another topic BTW)

Comment: I am trying to add the removed `RelativeLayout` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but it doesn't appear completely, `RecyclerView` hide part of it

Answer (score 0):

Put `RecyclerView` outside of `AppBarLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_sticky_header_store_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Name" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_scrollable_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#201A98E5"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="95dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_name_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:text="Name: "
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_name_scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_name_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_name_label_scrollable"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_quantity_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:text="Quantity: "
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_quantity_scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quantity_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_quantity_label_scrollable"
                    android:text="22" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_call_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_quantity_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:text="Call us"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_call_scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_quantity_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_call_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_call_label_scrollable"
                    android:text="0123456789" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_description_scrollable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_call_label_scrollable"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_logo"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text="Description description description description description description description description description description description" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_products"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round_top_corners_rectangle_gray"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_view" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```